# Why are my UTM links showing up in Google results?

Tags: google-analytics, utm-tracking, google-ads-api

https://www.google.com/search?q=kyledavidgroup+page2&oq=kyledavidgroup+page2&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l4.4703j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Why are my referral tracking links showing up as indexed pages in Google Searches for this site? (Link above is to show that they are showing up)

Answer (score 1):

Google will pickup UTM and other params under some circumstances, for instance if they are used in links. To prevent this:

- Have rel canonical on all pages (with no utm)
- In robots.txt you can disallow indexing of utm with:
- Disallow UTM paramater indexing in Google Search Console

Comment: Is it possible to exclude utm-links when doing a site search using Google (e.g., site:stackexhange.com search-term)?